# AJAX y WebAPI - Código faltante

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero saber que me le falta al siguiente código, en el que intento consumir datos de mi web api?

```
$("#txtGafete").keypress(function (e) {

    if(e.keyCode = 13)
    {
        var gafete = $("#txtGafete").val();
        var mm;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49851/api/empleadoAutorizado/" + gafete,
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#txtNombre").val(data.nombre);

            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: cual es el codigo de tu web api? espera json? el route espera ese parametro? coloca mas datos

Comment: Tienes al menos un error. El método **`"   GET"`** no existe. Deberías corregir, quitando los espacios en blanco: **`method: "GET"`**. Más adelante, considera usar `done` en lugar de `success`, ya que ésta última está en el punto de mira de la obsolescencia y yo dotaría a mi petición Ajax de un `fail` para mostrar algún mensaje cuando la petición falle.

Comment: corregi lo de los espacios en el metodo y con eso me funciono, lo de las peticiones del fail las estoy trabajando segun el usuario tenga o no acceso con mensajes pop-up, y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Estás intentando buscar el dato en `txtGafete` pero por `keyPress` evento. Puedes cambiar eso para `keydown` y así que ya tienes datos en input y presiona afuera, vas a enviar la solicitud al servidor. https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: Que le falta puedes ver en este otro tópico tuyo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152531/81977

Comment: Gracias Francis por la sugerencia ya solucione el error que tenia en ese codigo, gracias por tu sugerencia la tomare en cuenta en el momento que lo necesite

Comment: Perfecto @Reyes! Mucho gusto ayudarle :)